# Django REMOTE_USER does not exist but HTTP_REMOTE_USER does

Tags: django, httprequest, python-requests

All,

I have what should be a very simple problem. I am trying to use Django authentication using the REMOTE_USER variable following these instructions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/auth-remote-user/.

Then, to test that this is working, I am using the postman chrome extension. There I am setting a header variable with the name "REMOTE-USER" and then text for a superuser, and then I'm hitting the django admin page. I don't automatically login.

I set a break point in the process_request function in the `RemoteUserMiddleware` class. When I make the request, I see that `request.META["HTTP_REMOTE_USER"]` exists but `request.META["REMOTE_USER"]` does not exist. The default `RemoteUserMiddleware` variable uses `header="REMOTE_USER"`. It seems that HTTP Header variables gets a HTTP_ prefix, so I don't understand how this would ever work.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `REMOTE_USER` is meant to be an environment variable set by your web server (e.g. Apache), not an HTTP header. If it was an HTTP header, then users would be able to spoof the header, and log in as any user they wanted.

All http headers are prefixed `HTTP_` so that you can distinguish between them and environment variables.

You can set the environment variable with the development server as follows.

```
REMOTE_USER=admin ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: So is there any way to go about testing this? Can I set an environment variable manually? Also, as I understand it, yes, users would be able to spoof the header, but the use-case is that the app is behind a server which sets the REMOTE_USER and the app simply trusts that server.

Comment: Using http headers would be risky, because the server will let the header through unless it is suitably configured. Using environment variables prevents this as they can't be set by the user. Yes, you can set the environment variable when using `runserver`, see my updated answer.

Comment: you can set an environment variable manually using `os.environ`

Comment: Ah! This makes more sense now. I just have one outstanding misunderstanding. How in operation, how could a server on a separate machine set an environment variable on a separate machine that's running the app?

Comment: Before when you were saying environment variable, I thought you were referring to some HTTP environment variable. I didn't realize you meant environment variable as in a system environment variable.

Comment: @kicker86 Yes, you can set environment variables using `os.environ`, but I'm not sure that's particularly useful in this case. Where would you put the code to do that? Setting the environment variable when using runserver is probably the easiest way to test the `REMOTE_USER` authentication.

Comment: @Alasdair He is using the variable in tests, so wherever the test code is set up, or before it is executed.

Comment: @StephenHartzell you should not set an environment variable from another machine. You'd probably set it wherever you are running your tests, and maybe only for those particular tests that you are running.

Comment: @kicker86 The OP is running manual tests with an http client, not automated tests, so as I said, there is no obvious place to use `os.environ`.