# Not getting REMOTE_USER header in rails app running on passenger w/ nginx behind apache

Tags: apache, authentication, nginx, passenger, proxypass

So i'm transitioning a rails based website to Docker for the sake of it ;)

i use [phusion/passenger-docker](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker) to support my rails app. within it, i use [rack-webauth](https://github.com/nilclass/rack-webauth) which grabs WEBAUTH_USER or REMOTE_USER for the authentication piece. unfortunately, i can only use the Apache version of Stanford's Webauth to do the authentication; so i cannot (currently) use the nginx instance for this.

therefore, i use `ProxyPass` in the Apache instance to forward the traffic to my dockerised nginx'd application. the app works fine for the unauthenticated parts of my app; however, after i authenticate, my now dockerised app does not appear to see the REMOTE_USER environment variable (via a `puts env` in my ruby code).

My Apache config:

```
Listen 8443
<VirtualHost *:8443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/blah.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/blah.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/IntermediateCA.crt

   ServerAdmin blah@blah.com
   ServerName www.blah.com
   RewriteOptions inherit

   LogLevel    info
   ErrorLog    logs/web_error.log
   CustomLog   logs/web_access.log combined

   WebAuthCredCacheDir conf/webauth/credcache/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    <Location />
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        WebAuthExtraRedirect on
        AuthType WebAuth
        require valid-user
        RequestHeader merge REMOTE_USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{REMOTE_USER}]
    </Location>

   SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

(this same virtualhost definition in the non-dockerised webapp works fine - ie when i run my webapp under apache with the same Location stanza, it works and i see the REMOTE_USER)

And of course i run the dockerised webapp with

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:80 mywebapp
```

My sites definition in the dockerised nginx instance is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name blah.com;
  root /home/app/webapp/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_app_env development;

  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Might be a late answer, but hoping it will be useful for others.

Changing REMOTE_USER to HTTP_REMOTE_USER worked for me.

For more details, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508787/django-remote-user-does-not-exist-but-http-remote-user-does) answer clear.